Are positive definite linear operator always invertible?
Let us say that $T$ is a positive definite linear operator on an inner product space $\mathbf{V}$. Now, if $\mathbf{V}$ happens to be finite dimensional, then obviously $T$ would be invertible. But what if $\mathbf{V}$ isn't finite dimensional? I can show that $T$ is an injective operator since it can't have $0$ as its eigenvalue. However I'm not sure if $T$ is also surjective. If one can prove this statement, then $T$ would be invertible.
The method I have in mind relies on the fact that $R(T^*)^{\perp}=N(T)$, which holds true regardless of $\mathbf{V}$ being finite dimensional. Since $T$ is positive definite, $T^*=T$ and $N(T)=\{0\}$. So $R(T)^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Then if only we could show that $R(T)\oplus R(T)^{\perp}=\mathbf{V}$, my proof is complete. But the latter only holds true if $W=R(T)$ is finite dimensional, so that we could find for each vector $v$ in $\mathbf{V}$, two unique vectors $u \in W$ and $z \in W^{\perp}$ such that $v=u+z$ where $u = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k} \langle v,w_i \rangle w_i$ and $\{ w_1,w_2,...,w_k\}$ is the orthonormal basis for $W$. It may not be the case that $R(T)\oplus R(T)^{\perp}=\mathbf{V}$ if $R(T)$ isn't finite dimensional.
Am I missing something here? Is it possible to show that $W \oplus W^{\perp} = \mathbf{V}$, even when $W$ isn't finite dimensional? Or is there any way to say that a positive definite linear operator is invertible regardless of the dimension of $\mathbf{V}$?

Are you looking for a continuous inverse?

@copper.hat No. Just the inverse.

Positive operators with non-closed dense range exist. For instance let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $T:H\to H$ the operator
$$
Tx=\Big(x_1,\frac{x_2}2,\frac{x_3}3,\ldots\Big).
$$
Then
$$
\langle Tx,x\rangle=\sum_k\frac{|x_k|^2}{k}>0
$$
for all nonzero $x$. The range of $T$ is dense because each element in the canonical basis is in the range of $T$, for $e_n=T(ne_n)$ for each $n$. And the range of $T$ is not closed (equivalently, $T$ is not surjective); for example
$$
y=\Big(1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\Big)
$$
cannot be in the range of $T$, for the equality $Tx=y$ requires $x_k=1$ for all $k$, and the constant sequence $(1,1,\ldots)$ is not in $H$.
